# Java Throwing Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (nums[j] == target - nums[i]) {
                return new int[] { i, j };
            }
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
}
```

Here is the code to a LeetCode problem that asks to return an array of the two indices i and j such that nums[i] + nums[j] = target. The question states you can assume that there will be a solution.

I am wondering why instead of returning null if no solution is found you throw an exception? Wouldn't that be shown to the user?

Comment: Why instead of throwing an exception would you return null?

Comment: If there's assumed to be a solution, does it matter?

Comment: Because someone decided to throw an exception in tho case... since both approaches are equally possible this is mostly opinion based. One option: throw exception if this not expected to happen

Comment: Side note: this is likely wrong solution- you need O(n) and not O(n^2)

Comment: why don't you return `{0,0}` instead of throwing exception

Comment: @Deadpool Why would you?

Comment: he need to return `{i+j}==target`, there will only two case when he returns `{0,0}` either `target==0` or not match, he can verify `target==0` and do actions based on that @shmosel

Comment: @Deadpool You can't return `{0,0}` unless there are two 0's in `nums` and `target` is 0 too, since you're *required* to return two values from nums, and *required* to return pair adding up to `target`. Returning something else is a violation of the contract of the method, as stated in the requirements.

Comment: sorry i'm confused, is that indexes or values @Andreas

Comment: @Deadpool Sorry, I'm confusing you, since I didn't read close enough. Thought return values were values, not indexes. Doesn't matter, since my point still stands. You can't return `{0,0}` because: 1) two times value at index 0 is unlikely to equal `target`, and 2) you must return two different indexes, i.e. you cannot use the same value twice. Returning `{0,0}` would be an incorrect return value.

Comment: yes exactly, i'm just throwing an idea instead of throwing exception or returning null just return `{0,0}` and after calling `twoSum` method 1) check what it has returned, if array consists of `{0,0}` then say `nums[j] == target - nums[i]` failed always. 2) even if target is `0` since he is starting from 0+1==target (so there is no chance of returning `{0,0}` for any successful), i'm just telling instead of `exception` or `null` return something dummy and check it @Andreas

Comment: @Deadpool Did you miss the part where this is a LeetCode problem? Means LeetCode is the caller. You can't modify the caller, so it cannot "check what it has returned".

Answer (score 0):

Because there is supposed to always be a solution, so if no solution is found, that is an unexpected case, i.e. an *exception*.

If you return something else, you're ignoring the issue and silently returning incorrect result, violating the contract of the method. That is a problem because the caller is not expecting bad results, e.g. null, and will fail. Better to throw exception when it is detected, so it can provide the real cause of the issue.